# Webform Multiple Value Fieldset - Custom Email Values Print

Tags: webforms, emails

I have build a webform and installed this module [WFM](https://www.drupal.org/project/wfm) so user can insert multiple values on a certain fieldset.

Now i want to create a custom email template to print these values. 
For Simple text fields i write for example :

**[submission:values:FIELD-MACHINENAME:nolabel]**

What must i write??? to retrieve to retrieve each value of each fieldset :

For example the set of values for 1st fieldset is:

Fieldset-Name_FieldkeyName-1  Fieldset-Name_FieldkeySurname-1  Fieldset-Name_FieldkeyPhone-1

When user click for add more

Fieldset-Name_FieldkeyName-2  Fieldset-Name_FieldkeySurname-2  Fieldset-Name_FieldkeyPhone-2

Fieldset-Name_FieldkeyName-3  Fieldset-Name_FieldkeySurname-3  Fieldset-Name_FieldkeyPhone-3

..............................  and so on

How can i print these individually on custom email template?????